# set random pixels with imagesetpixel in specific color range

Tags: pixel

I wonder if it's possible to set the color of a pixel in an image, where the coordinate of the pixel is randomly chosen within a defined color.

For example an image (100x100) that contains 3 colors, red(4000px), black(3000px) and purple(3000px). Now I want to change 100 random red pixels into yellow.

I've played around with imagesetpixel, but can't figure out if it's possible to set the $x and $y randomly within a color range.

```
imagesetpixel ($image , $x , $y , $color )
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that we do not know how the different colored pixels are arranged in the image. In your case where you have many red pixels there is an easy method.

```
while(!exit):
   pixel = select random pixel
   if pixel.color = red:
       pixel.color = yellow
       exit = true
   end if
end while
```

This will change one pixel so you need to do that 100 times.

If you only have a few pixels of the color to change you may be better off first finding all pixels of one color and storing their coordinates in a list or an array and then randomly choosing one element of that data structure.

Comment: uhm.. How would I implement this in PHP. I Don't think that achieving my goal would be this easy... would it?

Comment: Which part is it that you don't know how to implement?

Comment: well, for example, how would you select the random pixels from an image. "select random pixel" obvious doesn't work with php. Do you use 'imagecolorat'?